# Erro ao usar SqlCommand e foreach

Tags: c#, sql-server, foreach

Estou tentando percorrer uma lista de objetos e persistir seus dados no SqlServer:

```
foreach (var item in pedidos)
{
   cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MinhaTabela (Coluna_A, Coluna_B, Coluna_C) " +
            "VALUES (@Val_A, @Val_B, @Val_C)";

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val_A", item.AttributoA);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val_B", item.AttributoB);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val_C", item.AttributoC);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Tenho recebido a seguinte `Exception`:

> The variable name '@Val_A' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Como resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se tem que adicionar o parâmetro e depois excluir para adicionar novamente porque no seu caso é uma interação de item e ainda pode mudar o `CommandText` para fora do `foreach`, só precisa saber isso uma única vez, ***exemplo***:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MinhaTabela (Coluna_A, Coluna_B, Coluna_C) " +
            "VALUES (@Val_A, @Val_B, @Val_C)";

foreach (var item in pedidos)
{       
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val_A", item.AttributoA);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val_B", item.AttributoB);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val_C", item.AttributoC);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   cmd.Parameters.Clear(); // adicione essa linha para limpar os parametros existentes.
}
```

tem outra forma que seria utilizar o mesmo parâmetro criado e mudar o seu valor, mas, o seu código teria que ficar verificando a existência ou não do parâmetro criado, acredito ser mais prático limpar os parâmetro e adicionar novamente, mas, vai um ***exemplo*** disso também:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MinhaTabela (Coluna_A, Coluna_B, Coluna_C) " +
            "VALUES (@Val_A, @Val_B, @Val_C)";

foreach (var item in pedidos)
{
    if (command.Parameters.Contains("@Val_A"))
    {
        command.Parameters["@Val_A"].Value = item.AttributoA;
    }
    else 
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val_A", item.AttributoA);
    }
    if (command.Parameters.Contains("@Val_B"))
    {
        command.Parameters["@Val_B"].Value = item.AttributoB;
    }
    else 
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val_B", item.AttributoB);
    }
    if (command.Parameters.Contains("@Val_C"))
    {
        command.Parameters["@Val_C"].Value = item.AttributoC;
    }
    else 
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val_C", item.AttributoC);
    }
}
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Classe SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Propriedade SqlCommand.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Cara, funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado.

Comment: Se for a resposta da sua pergunta aceite!

Comment: Vou aceitar sim, não o fiz ainda porque o S.O pede para aguardar alguns minutos para aceitar.